# Where is Java CLASSPATH in OSX?

Tags: java, macos, classpath

I have this file in my Home Directory on OSX:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and in Bash I am running:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ javac TestClass.java
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ java TestClass
Hello World
```

But I am wondering how the virtual machine instance running loads System from the CLASSPATH as my CLASSPATH environmental variable has no values:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ echo $CLASSPATH
```

Well it returns an empty row. Nothing. When echo $PATH I will see:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

And java itself is in:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ whereis java
/usr/bin/java
```

So in Windows java will look for the directories of CLASSPATH as far as I know. How does it work in OSX? How can Java load classes without the CLASSPATH variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the classpath, the bootstrap classloader loads the [core libraries](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=41) from /jre/lib and /jre/lib/ext ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader)).

You can check the classpath at runtime like this:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```